# Clear Focus of EditText when clicking on a button

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, android-button, input-field

Everyone,

I would like to achieve the following in my `Android` App:

I would like to create a view in which there are several input fields. 
An associated toolbar contains a save button.

If I have the focus in an EditText field and then press Save, I want the value of the edit field to be taken before saving.

So far I have created a workaround where a method `resetFocus()` is called before saving which does the following:

```
if (binding.volume.hasFocus()) binding.volume.clearFocus();
```

Is there a clean way to implement the request without such a help method?

Thx for you help

Comment: Hey @Vincent, would it be possible for you to add more details to your question? Code snippet would be more helpful to understand what exactly you are doing in your code. Cheers!

Comment: Just call `clearFocus` directly...